# Can't Connect to Minecraft Server but can Connect to LAN

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I can't connect to any Minecraft servers. When I try to connect, it gives me this error message: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information:`. Here's what I've tried:

1. Added outgoing port for 25565
2. Deleting .minecraft folder
3. Connecting to a Realm (I could connect)
4. Connecting to a LAN world (I could connect)
5. Trying it from a different account but same computer
6. Trying it from the same account different computer (in the same network)
7. Trying it from a different account different computer (in the same network)

However, trying it from the same account on a different computer worked! Can someone help me?

Comment: Wait, did it work as well from a different account on a different PC? (which I assume is inside the same network?)

Comment: It did work from a different account on a different PC. It is in the same network, and I will edit the question to add this.

Comment: What error is showing up when you try to connect? Timeout or something else?

Comment: It gives me `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information:`. I will edit the question to add this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to state what the issue is here without going into some [SE.SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) territory, but I believe one of these suggestions will fix your issue. You've tested and determined that the server is reachable from a different PC on the same network. *It's clear that the problem isn't with Minecraft* as it's only affecting first PC and only when connecting to a third-party server. We'll need to figure out if it's a problem with Windows or a problem with your home router.

1. **Turn off Windows Firewall**

Assuming you're using Windows 7+, you'll want to see if [turning the built-in firewall off fixes the issue.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766337%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> To disable the **firewall** portion of *Windows Firewall with Advanced Security* by using the Windows Firewall Control Panel program
>
> - Click **Start**, click **Control Panel**, click **Network and Internet**, and then under **Windows Firewall**, click **Turn Windows Firewall on or off**.
> - On the General tab of the Windows Firewall Settings dialog box, select **Off (not recommended)**, and then click **OK**.
>
> Link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766337%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If this fixes the problem, you'll want to re-enable the firewall, and [setup a firewall exception in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/144482/windows-firewall-how-to-allow-traffic-on-a-specific-port-eg-8080).

2. **Place the PC on the router's DMZ**

Assuming that turning the firewall off didn't work, this should be your next step. In this one you'll have to research how do it as it's different steps and locations even for the same brand and manufacturer. Generally speaking though, a home router will offer the option to place a device in DMZ, or "non-protected" status. The idea behind this is that all traffic will be directly to the IP address in DMZ first unless stated as a forward otherwise. ***This should only be for testing purposes***. If it works on DMZ, then you'll want to check your forwarding settings again and see if the ports and destination IP is correct.  ***Leaving a computer on the DMZ leaves it open to any and all connections***, which makes it a possible target to people and bots with malice intent, but also removes any and all possible restrictions

3. **Repair Windows TCP/IP stack**

If the other two options do not work, there's something most likely messing with outbound connections. At this point, I would see if [repairing your TCP/IP settings would fix the issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299357).

> Click on the **Start** button, type **cmd** and right-click on **Command Prompt**; slect "Run as Administrator" from the context menu.
>
> Inside the new *Command Prompt* window, type:
>
> ```
> netsh int ip reset
> ```
>
> When complete, reboot the PC.
>
> Link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299357

Repairing the TCP/IP stack should disconnect any additional drivers and leave only the windows one behind.  If this doesn't fix the issue, there might be a bigger problem you'll want a repair shop to look into.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this! I tried number 1, and was going to try the others, but after I updated my PC to the latest version of Windows 10 it now works. It may be completely unrelated, but now it works! :)

Comment: Great to hear! I was considering adding Windows 10 updates, but that's very unlikely to "fix" it in most cases. It just as likely that the latest updates also fixed the network driver. (or clear away some other issue!) #GREATJOB

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, this error message shows when other computers connected to the same router are using much more Internet than I am, causing a very unstable connection.

My suggestion would be to try to get everyone else using that Internet service to stop for a few moments, then try to join the server. Once you've got a stable connection, all the others can continue doing what they're doing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After updating my PC to the latest version of Windows 10 it now works. Thanks!